# Find the Fourier Series of f(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

I am trying to solve the following fourier series:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x}{l} &\mbox{if  } 0 \leq x \leq l \\
\frac{2l - x}{l} &\mbox{if  } l \leq x \leq 2l \\
\end{cases} $$

I know that $\frac{x}{l}$ is an odd function. The one below $2l - x / l$ is neither even/odd. I am not sure how to proceed finding the coefficients

Comment: something missing in the question.

Comment: what do you think is missing?

Comment: Ah - do you mean the one above (not below, because there is nothing below...)?

Comment: If you mean the function above, then you can either find the fourier series for the odd extension of f to $[-2l,2l]$ or the even extension to $[-2l,2l]$.